# Trouble printing in order, post order ect for a binary tree

Tags: c++

I am having trouble printing my in order, pre order, and post order of my binary tree. I had it working when I was reading from cin. However, now that I am reading from a txt file, my in order, pre order and post order all print out what was read in from the txt file. I have provided the code that I believe the problem is in, please comment if you need to see the rest of my code.

My code:

```
int main()
{
    vector <BinaryTree <string> > BT;
    int iteration = 0;

    string line;
    ifstream myfile("input.txt");
    if (myfile.is_open())
    {
        while(getline (myfile, line))
        {
            BinaryTree <string> temptree;
            BT.push_back(temptree);
            BT[iteration].InsertData(line);

            cout << "Preorder: ";
            BT[iteration].PrintPreorder();
            cout << endl;
            cout << "Inorder: ";
            BT[iteration].PrintInorder();
            cout << endl;
            cout << "Postorder: ";
            BT[iteration].PrintPostorder();
            cout << endl;
            cout << "Reverse Inorder: ";
            BT[iteration].PrintReverseInorder();
            cout << endl;

            BT[iteration].PrintPrintTree();
            cout << endl;
            iteration++;
        }

        myfile.close();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "However, now that I am reading from a txt file, my in order, pre order and post order all print out what was read in from the txt file." -- Sounds about right. What's the problem?

Comment: If my file reads 'abcd', my inorder, preorder, and postorder all print out 'abcd'. But postorder should print out the reverse 'dcba'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your input supposed to be one character at a time? It looks like you are accepting lines of text when you want to be accepting characters one at a time, which would explain your output ('abcd' is a single node, your root).

Comment: How would I change it to one character at a time? Now that you explain it like that, I feel like this could be the problem

Comment: Your program is grabbing input line by line, so either use get() to retrieve one character from the stream at a time or put every element of the tree in its own line in the input file